# Complete Similarities

Tags: fluid-mechanics, automotive-engineering

Regarding the similarities, I know that the complete similarity is not always possible because all geometric, kinematic, dynamic similarity can not be met simultaneously.

Is it because **both** geometric and dynamic similarity can **not** be achieved at the same time?

What's the reasons? Please give some examples and explanations.

Comment: how do you get a 1/10 model of an airplane to give the required results? by juggling with the parameters you want compared to the others... One change was to swap air for water which means almost a factor of 1000 change for density... and viscosity etc but other values provided the required info.

Answer (score 1):

Complete similarity (Similitude) is not always possible because complete modeling is not always possible.

**Geometric Similarity** is easy.  We just need the model to be a good scale representation.

**Kinematic Similarity** is harder because we need the test conditions to mirror expected system conditions.  Can you mirror expected temperature, pressure, and speed?

**Dynamic Similarity** is also hard because the boundary conditions and boundary layer characteristics need to match between model and actual.  Dynamic similarity needs Kinematic Similarity (similar forces are required to make the dynamics similar), and Kinematic needs Geometric (or else we could not compare forces).  As a result, we cannot achieve dynamic without geometric.  Dynamic Similarity is extremely hard to achieve in some flow conditions, like high-speed aerodynamics where the fluid can no longer be considered incompressible.  But even in low-flow conditions it can be difficult to achieve, which is why the topic is complex, and why flow modeling in general is difficult.